# Importing fixed-width text files to Mysql with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, import

I'm trying to import fixed with text files into a Mysql table. I'm digging around for answers, but my main issue is that I can't figure out the logic of how I should do this.  Maybe someone could offer some hints on process:

**Steps**
1. `fopen` the file

```
$file_handle = fopen("thefile.txt", "r");
```

2. Use `feof` to go to the end of the file.  Separate each line.   (I have know idea why, but that $output line works.

```
 while (!feof($file_handle) ) {  
 $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);  
 $lines = explode('|', $line_of_text);  
 $output = $lines[0] . $lines[1]. "<BR>";
```

All of this works fine.  It reads the fixed-width file, and displays it all as it should - line by line. But how do I setup the columns before I import it to Mysql?

I thought maybe doing something like this might do the trick to define the right columns:

```
echo substr($output,0,5);
echo substr($output,5,10);
echo substr($output,16,5);
```

But that doesn't work.   Basically, can someone outline the steps I need to go through?  I'm not asking for a solution, but at the moment, I don't even know what to Google for when I don't know what steps should come next.

Sorry for the complete beginner question here, but any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Terry

*[I'm not 100% sure how to import to Mysql either, but I wanted to get this much out of the way.  IE: How do I setup the substrings to define my columns]*

Answer (score 0):

Fixed width files (with seperate portions of data) are best handled with [fscanf](http://www.php.net/fscanf)

```
while($data=fscanf("%5s%10s%5s\n",$file_handle)){
    var_dump($data);
}
```

However, `explode`ing on '|' makes me think [fgetcsv](http://www.php.net/fgetcsv) may work too, and if that works a `LOAD DATA` command in MySQL could possibly skip PHP altogether.

Comment: fgetcsv for fixed width?  I only used the '|' because I found it in a tutorial - anything works (=, *, etc...anything).

Comment: Nah, `fgetcsv` is for delimited data, not fixed width. The fact that you were exploding on `|` made me think there could be delimiters making life more pleasant.