# Handling non-comma-delimited data in a txt file with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, text

I have a substantial amount of data that needs imported into a MySQL database. I'm used to importing comma and tab delimited data, but this is different, I will try to explain the format in the most simple terms below.

So it could be:

```
XXX XXX XXX
```

or it could be:

```
XXX   X XXX
```

or it could be:

```
X     X  XX
```

I hope the spaces show correctly! If so you'll see that each character has its allocated space, rather than having 3 sections delimited by spaces, tabs or commas. (they are technically delimited by spaces, but by differing numbers).

What I need to do, is say characters 1, 2 and 3 go into field_1 in the DB. Character 4 is always blank, and characters 5, 6 and 7 go into field_2, etc. Essentially each section must be in it's own field.

Now, I suppose I could import it as all one field into a temporary table, and perhaps use SUBSTR() to arrange this data into the correct format as described above.

But that seems a bit long winded.

Is there a better way to do this? I'd hopefully like to import it directly into the correct format in the DB from the text file, without taking any additional steps.

Thanks

Comment: You can use substr, but I'd not do it in pure sql. Just read each line, use http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php to get your 3 variables, and insert.

Comment: This is called "fixed-width data", btw, and is pretty common.  See for example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876092/importing-fixed-width-text-files-to-mysql-with-php

Comment: Thanks Mellamokb, that's mega helpful! One of the reasons I posted the question here is because I didn't know what it was called, and thus was really struggling to search for anything useful on the subject. I've never came across it before.

Comment: Nanne, this was one of my first thoughts but assumed it would be really resource hungry and potentially take longer?

Comment: Compared to a loadfile kinda thing in mysql, sure, but if you're reading the file in PHP anyway (I mean, you've tagged the question php) I don't see the issue. You could always try it (it's not a big deal, you need 3 `substr`'s, so it's not that much work) and see how fast it is :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the PHP substr() route, and although it worked, I found it was taking a long time to process the data looping through each row, and given that I have hundreds of thousands of records to process, felt it was too slow.

As an alternative, I found this simple SQL solution, which processes the data very quickly:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL 
    INFILE 'fixed-width-data.txt' 
INTO TABLE 
    my_table (@line)
SET 
    field_1 = SUBSTR(@line,1,3),
    field_2 = SUBSTR(@line, 5,3),
    field_3 = SUBSTR(@line, 9,3)
```

Answer (score -1):

`substr()` is one option, but regular expressions might be more elegant to work with. For your example where characters 1 through 3 are one field and 5 through 7 are another, you could do…

```
preg_match('/^(.{3}).(.{3})$/', $line_of_data, $matches);
$field_one = $matches[1];
$field_two = $matches[2];
```

This is obviously a simplified example, but I think that if you have many "fields" of data to work with, you'll find that using regular expressions instead of `substr()` over and over a lot more pleasant to work with in the long run.

Comment: Thanks Garret. I keep meaning to use regular expressions more often, I think you're right. Not sure why your answer has been voted down - a comment would be useful, but I suspect it was unintentional?

Comment: Who knows. But feel free to mete justice on the scoundrel by voting it back up or maybe even accepting it. =P